# Reasons for unlocking EOS wallet before importing private keys

Tags: cleos

I've been wondering about this. Is there a reason why you need to unlock the EOS wallet before importing Private Keys into it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The password is used to encode the private keys stored in the wallet.
So, if you don't know the password, you can't see the private key, even with full access to the computer storing the wallet.
Conversely, when a `keosd` instance doesn't yet know the password, it can't encode the keys while importing them.